# Download Apache error_log

Tags: apache, webserver

Newby programmer here; I have a generic Apache webserver, and am wondering how I can download the error_log. I have figured out how to use PuTTy to view the log, but the log is massive, and I want to download the file so that I can analyze it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can `scp` the file using putty's `psftp.exe`.

Comment: Thanks Kenney, I'll try that. Is there a way to view the file size (before transferring it)? I know it's large, just don't know *how* large.

Comment: `du -h /var/log/apache2/access.log` (in the shell); btw, `less /var/log/apache2/....` is a decent viewer; it has scrolling, searching etc..